# Load Data Infile Not Insert Data to phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, sql, csv

I tried to change from **insert to** to **load data infile** for uploading a large CSV file.

I explored some examples on how to use **load data infile**. But it's not working and giving this Error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 29 File '/direct1/@tmp/phpFZLLYA' not found (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied").

**This is my code:**

```
$target_dir = '/direct1/@tmp/'; 
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

$stmt = $dbcon->prepare("LOAD DATA INFILE '$target_file' INTO TABLE Rain FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES(id, date, vol, day)"); 
$stmt->execute();
```

When I try to change to **load data local infile** based on related discussion, error code does not appear but the data is not inserted to the database. I am using `INNODB storage engine`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the error by using **move_uploaded_file** function and the file can be access.